# Shell - How can I grep a particular word in a sentence?

Tags: shell, grep, words

I want to grep some part of the sentence, for example: `/hana/new/register`. In this I need to grep the first element between the `/` characters, so here I want to get `hana`.

How can I do that in shell?

Comment: 3 Steps. You might want to separate the string by the "/" character, take the first item of the array, take the range of that first string and then grep.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first word on a slash-separated line, we can use `cut`:

```
$ echo '/samarth/new/register then i want to grep samarth' | cut -d/ -f 2
samarth
$ echo '/hana/new/register' | cut -d/ -f 2
hana
```

Or, we can use `awk`:

```
$ echo '/samarth/new/register then i want to grep samarth' | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
samarth
$ echo '/hana/new/register' | awk -F/ '{print $2}'
hana
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin And so does your sed. +1.

Comment: All considered, `awk` is probably the less cryptic of the two (in this case `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` and capture whatever is between the first `/.../` using a *character class* and *back reference*. For example:

```
echo '/samarth/new/register' | sed 's/^\/\([^/]*\).*$/\1/'
samarth
```

Where the `sed` command is the basic *substitute* command with the form `sed 's/find/replace/'` where you find everything after the first `/` (escaped as `\/`) and anchored to the beginning with `^`. You use a capture group `\(...\)` to capture the character class `[^/]*` (everything not a `/`) and in the *replace* side of the substitute, you use the backreference `\1` to put what you first captured in as the *replace*.